# Ubuntu freezes running the first time

Tags: 12.04, grub2, wubi, dell, boot-failure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

12.04 Freezes on first run after install, loading screen says 'Preparing to run Ubuntu for the first time...' — stuck on 2nd dot after a few cycles.

On Dell Inspiron B130

Installed using Windows Installer

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't ever used the Windows installer, so I unfortunately can't help you too much.  I have the same computer though, and it wouldn't boot because of the b43 firmware.

The solution was to blacklist the b43 module via GRUB and then install the `firmware-b43-installer` once Ubuntu is loaded. [(More information here)](http://clusterbleep.net/blog/2012/05/09/ubuntu-12-04-splash-screen-lockup-with-livecd/)

According to the [WubiGuide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide), here is how to edit the GRUB command line options on wubi installs:

> For grub errors, immediately after reboot, press [<kbd>INSERT</kbd>] rapidly after selecting  Wubi and/or press [<kbd>ESC</kbd>] at the countdown after selecting "Ubuntu" and use [<kbd>C</kbd>] or [<kbd>E</kbd>] to enter the appropriate boot options manually

## What you should do:

1. Use the above directions, then enter in `b43.blacklist=yes` and press 
   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot.
2. Install the `firmware-b43-installer` package.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
   ```
3. Reboot and you *should* have a working system with wireless.

**Note:** I haven't tried this so post a comment if something doesn't work quite right.